# How to Access window phone 7 inbox message

Tags: windows-phone-7, window

I am currently developing window phone 7 application, i want to access window phone inbox the last unread message. Its possible to develop in window phone 7 apps. Its possible? If so the kindly send me the following steps.

Window Phone 7 Apps have one problem, any third party MAPI or DLL not supporting WP7 apps will work only with window phone assemblies.

Answer (score 3):

In the current version 7.0 you cannot directly access the inbox.
You can use Choosers and Launchers to get access to send email from any of the configured accounts on the user device.

Do have a look at the documentation for next version of WP7 SDK code named 'Mango' which has more rich features enabling more access to existing functionality.